# facebook fanpage geotaggig map

Tags: facebook, dictionary, geotagging

Is there a way to have a map on my facebook fanpage with geotaggs from my photos similar with instagram map ??
I have a lots of pictures and i”ve put on everyone location so it would be nice to find a way to display my route on a map.

10x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide full code for you to do this, but if you are prepared to put a little bit of code together, this should be pretty simple:

1. Get a list of photos from your Page. You can do this via Graph API with either the [/pageid/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos) or [/pageid/tagged/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections) connections. You will of course require [an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) in order to request this information.
2. This will give you a list of Photo IDs, so you should now iterate through these IDs one by one (or using Batch Graph API requests) and request the [Graph API object for each Photo ID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). In each object will be a `place` field (if the location has been tagged, and if the user whose access token you are using is able to view the photo) which contains a Place ID.
3. For each of those Place IDs, there may be (some Places lack this) a `location` field which will contain a latitude and a longitude.
4. Use these Geo-points with an API for Google, Bing or some other mapping software to create an HTML page with a map filled with markers that highlight each of the photos.
5. [Use this HTML page as your Page Tab URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) for a Facebook app and then follow [these instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) to add this as a tab to your Facebook Page.

Done.